# Django rest framework probleme

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-urls

here is my code :

```
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from .api import ListViewSet, CardViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'lists', ListViewSet,'lists')
router.register(r'cards', CardViewSet, 'cards')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

but When i run the server i got this error :

```
Page not found (404) Request Method:
GET Request URL: http://localhost:8000/scrumboard/cards Using the URLconf defined in djangularApp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/ ^$ ^scrumboard ^lists/$ [name='lists-list'] ^scrumboard
^lists\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='lists-list'] ^scrumboard
^lists/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='lists-detail'] ^scrumboard
^lists/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='lists-detail']
^scrumboard ^cards/$ [name='cards-list'] ^scrumboard
^cards\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='cards-list'] ^scrumboard
^cards/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='cards-detail'] ^scrumboard
^cards/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='cards-detail']
^scrumboard ^$ [name='api-root'] ^scrumboard
^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
The current path, scrumboard/cards, didn't match any of these.
```

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you forgot to add a /  after the `scrumboard` url, likely where you include the the router's urls.
This is visible as the `^scrumboard ^cards/$` should be `^scrumboard/ ^cards/$` to match the url you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have not registered the url i.e in your `project/urls.py`

`path('api/', include((router.urls), namespace='api')),`

That means the path will start with `/api/cards`

OR for `/scrumboard`

`path('scrumboard/', include((router.urls), namespace='scrumboard')),`

Then you can use `/scrumboard/cards`